# PHP ftp_put files are uploading, but I cannot find them on my server

Tags: php, file, upload, large-files

so I am the webmaster/in charge collecting the files for a music video contest. The problem is I only know HTML, CSS, limited PHP, and some Actionscript 2. I need to be able to allow people to upload large files to my server (the videos they are submitting) but I am unable to find a way to do that. I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions of an upload system that work work for me. I have tired PHP's ftp_put but the files seem to be too large for it to handle. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work for very large files, but I do some image uploading using a form and file inputs like so:

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="upload.php">
<input type="file" name="file" />
</form>
```

PHP

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $server_path . $new_file_name);
```

You can also upload multiple files like so:

HTML

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php">
<input type="file" name="files[]" />
<input type="file" name="files[]" />
<input type="file" name="files[]" />
</form>
```

PHP

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['images']['error']); $i++)
{
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $server_path . $new_file_name[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know for example youtube, as well as facebook have a process that uploads the files by parts ... but I don't know how it happens.
Another way would be to create an ftp account for each user and then they can use a program like [filezila](http://filezilla-project.org/).
The other way, I think it would be an application in Java.

Answer (score 0):

large files can also be handled by ftp_put, check your settings for upload_max_filesize, post_max_size, max_execution_time, max_input_time, and memory_limit in your php.ini file. These could all affect your file uploading abilities.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with PHP uploading is that typically there's a file size limit and there's a server timeout limit as well, as in if the script is running for so long, it will time out. This becomes a problem in uploading larger files. If you can modify these settings yourself on your server then I suggest you try [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/)